# How or which solver find solution that holds strictly complementary slackness condition

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, matlab, karush-kuhn-tucker

So as theoretical I know interior point generate a solution in which the solution satisfies ***strictly** **complementary slackness*** condition. but when i use solver like linprog (by specifying 'interior-point' in matlab) or gurobi or SDPT3 or SeDumi solver, the final solution dose not hold **strictly complementary slackness** condition.
so is there any solver which find optimal solution that holds strictly complementary slackness condition?
or are there any ways or methods to convert a solution find by this solver to a solution which satisfies the strictly complementary slackness condition?

[image]

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: "the final solution dose not hold strictly complementary slackness condition" Please post this case.

Comment: yes, the final vector for problem's variables which solver return, dual and primal variables dose not satisfy SCS.

Comment: OK. Post the example and the result of the solver.

Comment: I wasn´t able to open the file (which file?), sorry,

Comment: I cannot open the file without registration at google cloud. But I don´t want that. You can upload pictures and you can write some information and data  into the question field. It works for almost all kinds of questions.

Comment: ok, so as the picture,  you can see three columns, first column is the solution vector that the matlab lingprog( ) function returned by specifying the method to 'interior point'. the second column is lower bound of each variable in V. as you can see, the value of v_i (red box) are zero and also the lower bound is zero too, but the value of dual (third column) is zero. as I know interior point generate a solution in which the solution satisfies strictly complementary slackness condition, since the dual have to be non-zero but here is zero. how can find solution which is SCS?